# resignFirstResponder issue with UITextField in custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have an `UITableView` with custom `UITableViewCell` Each cell contain a `UILabel` and `UITextField` as below. I have added a `Done` button at top of the keyboard for hiding the keyboard.

[image]

Now suppose the textField of second row is `firstResponder`, at that time if I scroll the table view to top and move out the second row from visible rect. Now if I press the `Done` key then and method got fired where I use `[[self view] endEditing:YES];` the application got crashed.

To solve that I implement the below method and I got success.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndDisplayingCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    for(UIView *contentView in [[cell contentView] subviews])
    {
        if([contentView isKindOfClass:[UIView class]])
        {
            for(UITextField *textField in [contentView subviews])
            {
                if([textField isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]] && [textField isFirstResponder])
                {
                    [textField resignFirstResponder];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now the problem is if I do the same scenario when the second row move out from the visible rect the above method got fired and keyboard is automatically hide as expected. But at that time when I drag table view to down and again move in the second row to visible rect it's color got changed.
 [image]

To solve the color issue I implement the below method but it's not working

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
}
```

And not only the color issue. Again if I touch to textField of the second row keyboard is shown and if I do the same scenario `tableView didEndDisplayingCell` method not fired for that cell. Even if I press the `Done` key application got crashed. Exception brake point pointing to `[[self view] endEditing:YES];` and error shown [image]

Guys please help me. I had waste a lot of time to figure out but I fail.

Comment: Can you show the whole method where `[[self view] endEditing:YES]` is called ?

Comment: I called `[[self view] endEditing:YES];` on touch event of the button attached with keyboard

Answer (score 2):

When a cell is scrolled out of view and is removed, UIKit calls didEndDisplayingCell.  However, when it has an edit control with focus, didEndDisplayingCell does not get called.

One possible alternative is to dismiss keyboard on drag by setting

```
tableView.keyboardDismissMode = .OnDrag
```

This causes the UITextView to give up first responder and consequently didEndDisplayingCell is called.

More detail [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/18607).